# How to utilise ffmpeg to to extract key frames from a video stream and only print the labels present within these frames?

Tags: python, tensorflow, video, ffmpeg, object-detection

So a bit of context, I'm using the TensorFlow object detection API for a project, and I've modified the visualization_utils file to print any present class labels to the terminal and then write them to a .txt file. From a bit of research I've come across FFmpeg, I'm wondering if there is a function I can use in FFmpeg so that it only prints and writes the class labels from keyframes within the video? - i.e. when there is a change in the video. At the moment it is printing all the class labels per frame even if there is no change, so I have duplicate numbers of labels even if there is no new object within the video. Following on from this, would I have to apply this keyframe filtering to an input video beforehand?

Thanks in advance!

I'm using opencv2 to capture my video input.

Please see below for code:

visualization_utils.py - inside the draw_bounding_box_on_image_array function:

```
# Write video output to file for evaluation.

  f = open("ObjDecOutput.txt", "a")
  print(display_str_list[0])
  f.write(display_str_list[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd just follow up on this, I ended up using ffmpeg mpdecimate and setpts filters to remove duplicate and similar frames.

```
ffmpeg -i example.mp4 -vf mpdecimate=frac=1,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB  example_decimated.mp4
```

This however didn't solve the problem of duplicates within the file I was writing the labels to - to solve this I appended each row in the file to a list and looped through it to remove groups of duplicated elements and only kept the first occurrence and appended that to a new list.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution [here](https://superuser.com/a/1708661) after a year. However, there is a small bug in the code converted from [this script](https://gist.github.com/alastairmccormack/7041ee993adb5c911f90#file-iframe-probe-py).

The fix is `and frame["key_frame"]`

```
import json
import subprocess

def get_frames_metadata(file):
    command = '"{ffexec}" -show_frames -print_format json "{filename}"'.format(ffexec='ffprobe', filename=file)
    response_json = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, stderr=None)
    frames = json.loads(response_json)["frames"]
    frames_metadata, frames_type, frames_type_bool = [], [], []
    for frame in frames:
        if frame["media_type"] == "video":
            video_frame = json.dumps(dict(frame), indent=4)
            frames_metadata.append(video_frame)
            frames_type.append(frame["pict_type"])
            if frame["pict_type"] == "I" and frame["key_frame"]:
                frames_type_bool.append(True)
            else:
                frames_type_bool.append(False)
#     print(frames_type)
    return frames_metadata, frames_type, frames_type_bool
```

The frame types are stores in `frames_type`, but don't trust it. True keyframes are in `frames_type_bool`.
I tested a clip for which I had two consecutive I-frames at the beginning, but **avidemux** was showing only one. So I checked the original code and found that some frames may have `pict_type = I` but `key_frame = False`. I thus fixed the code.

After having the `frames_type_bool`, you can extract the True indices and **opencv** or **imageio** to extract keyframes only.

This is how to use this function and **imageio** to show the keyframes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import imageio

filename = 'Clip.mp4'

# extract frame types
_,_, isKeyFrame = get_frames_metadata(filename)

# keep keyframes indices
keyframes_index = [i for i,b in enumerate(isKeyFrame) if b]

# open file
vid = imageio.get_reader(filename,  'ffmpeg')

for i in keyframes_index:
    image = vid.get_data(i)
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle('image #{}'.format(i), fontsize=20)
    plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```